# Why covariance with Func<TResult> doesn't work?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates, covariance

```
int FuncA()
{
    return 0;
}

Func<int> a = FuncA;
Func<object> b = a;
```

Why compiler doesn't allow to assign a to b? According to covaraince principle it should, shince object is the base to int.

Comment: I'm guessing this has something to do with the fact that it would result in boxing.

Comment: I think this might answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28095804/put-a-struct-as-a-generic-covariant-parameter

Comment: Every value type declaration actually defines two related kinds of thing: a storage location type, and a boxed object type.  The latter derives from `Object`, but the former doesn't derive from anything.

Comment: @supercat so, covariance doesn't work for value types?

Comment: @CoolCoder: It can be used in some cases involving a generic type parameter with an interface constraint.  For example, I think one could have a function that accepts a generic argument which is constrained to IEnumerable<Animal>.  I think such a function could accept a `List<Cat>.Enumerator` even though that would be a value type, but it's been ages since I've looked at such things.